# Can a directory be made a ninja dependency?

Tags: build, ninja

Ninja builds can take a file as a dependency.  Can they take directories as dependencies, so that if the dir has been written to - perhaps a file added or deleted - the rule is triggered?

(Context: Consider the example

```
# Regenerate build files if build script changes.
rule configure
  command = ${configure_env}python $root/configure.py $configure_args
  generator = 1
build build.ninja: configure | $root/configure.py $root/misc/ninja_syntax.py
```

I'd like to make that depend not only on the build script, but any changes to its dir.)